# How to put widgets inside a ttk.Button

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a proper way to nest widgets inside of a [ttk.Button](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Button.html)? It supports specifying a label (a `str`) and image (a `PhotoImage`) which I assume is implemented using children widgets.

Here's an example where I'm adding a left-aligned and a right-aligned label to a button.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

normal_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Normal Button")
normal_button.pack(fill=tk.X)

custom_button = ttk.Button(root)
custom_button.pack(fill=tk.X)
left_label = ttk.Label(custom_button, text="Left")
left_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=16, pady=4)
right_label = ttk.Label(custom_button, text="Right")
right_label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=16, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```

This sort of works, but there are some quirks:

- When hovering over the button, the button's background is highlighted but the nested labels keep their unhighlighted backgrounds.
- If I click within either nested label, the button will press down, but will not become unpressed.
- When the button is pressed, the nested labels will not shift giving the illusion of a button being pressed.

Is there a proper way to pack widgets inside of a button?

Comment: I think `Button` rather wasn't designed for nesting other widgets.  You could create own Widget using `Frame` and binding events  `<Button-1>`, `<Enter>`, `<Leave>`.

Comment: besides `Label` never change background color on mouse hover so why should it do it inside button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in a comment you can create your own widget.

Here is a simple example with `tk.Frame` and `tk.Label` (`ttk.Label` needs more work with `ttk.Style`).

I bind events `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` to change frame and labels backgrounds.

For more widgets you could keep them in a list and use a `for` loop to change the background.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class MyButton(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, bg_hover='red', bg_normal=None, **options):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **options)

        self.bg_normal = bg_normal
        self.bg_hover = bg_hover

        # use default color if bg_normal is `None`
        if not self.bg_normal:
            self.bg_normal = self['bg']

        # add first label
        self.left_label = tk.Label(self, text="Left")
        self.left_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=16, pady=4)

        # add second label
        self.right_label = tk.Label(self, text="Right")
        self.right_label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=16, pady=4)

        # bind events
        self.bind('<Enter>', self.on_enter)
        self.bind('<Leave>', self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, event=None):
        # change all backgrounds on mouse enter
        self['bg'] = self.bg_hover
        self.left_label['bg'] = self.bg_hover
        self.right_label['bg'] = self.bg_hover

    def on_leave(self, event=None):
        # change all backgrounds on mouse leave
        self['bg'] = self.bg_normal
        self.left_label['bg'] = self.bg_normal
        self.right_label['bg'] = self.bg_normal


root = tk.Tk()

normal_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Normal Button")
normal_button.pack(fill=tk.X)

my_button = MyButton(root)
my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no proper way to pack widgets inside a button. Buttons aren't designed for that feature. As you've seen, you can indeed use `pack` or `grid` to put widgets inside of buttons. However, you'll have to add custom bindings to make it appear as if it's all one button widget.